# Can't get gl.ALPHA channel to work in WebGL 1

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to use the following combination instead of using gl.RGBA to save space:

- internal format: gl.ALPHA
- format: gl.ALPHA
- type: gl.FLOAT

in WebGL 1 along with a `OES_texture_float extenion`. However each time I draw I get an INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION.

If I switch to gl.RGBA for both internal format and format then everything runs smoothly.

These are my initialization attributes:

```
contextAttributes = {
    alpha: false,
    depth: false,
    antialias: false,
    stencil: false,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: false,
    premultipliedAlpha: false,
    failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat: true
  };
```

Comment: `OES_texture_float` is definitely supported. I can just switch from `gl.ALPHA` to `gl.RGBA` and everything works as normal. Have tried it on Chrome and Edge with similar results

Comment: Its not supported. Only RGB and RGBA are color renderable formats. https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_color_buffer_float/

Comment: @pleup thanks very much!